# Purchases and updates after changing AppleID & Primary Email Address

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id

I want to switch my AppleID from using my ISP email addrress to my gmail address.
If I change both my AppleID and Primary Email Address [as directed](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5621), (I understand I'll need to log out and log back in to the app store on each device,) will my existing purchases (apps & music) still be available for use and updates?

Comment: they should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked as expected/hoped.

The main stumbling block that I hit was that my new AppleID address was already in use as my emergency email address (I deleted this to allow me to make it my primary email address).

The actual change went smoothly and without issue, afterwards all I needed to do was to log back into iTunes and my phone using my new AppleID.